# CLLocationManager - kCLErrorDomain

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I have a CLLocation manager. It works fine.

```
locManager = CLLocationManager()
locManager.delegate = self
locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

And of course, I have the delegate methods:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        println("didfail")
        println(error)
    }

func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {
        println("location manager called..")
        let locationLast = locations.last as! CLLocation

        latitude = locationLast.coordinate.latitude.description
        longitude = locationLast.coordinate.longitude.description

        locManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

       //....
    }
```

There is no any problem it's working! But, when i'm here 47.5775679 19.0488392 (or at in 1-2km radius of this point ) it's throws this error:

> Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

I was tried with simulator and real devices too. I have internet connection on the real devices when i was trying. Is there a black hole? :) or i don't know.

Could anybody please give me any idea about, what cause this phenomenon?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to run Maps app while at the same location? Does it show your location? Is accuracy good?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happen when your device is not able find out your location from actual GPS system , wifi or internet. My observation is that when device(it was iPhone 4 for my case) is in a close room and connected with Wifi using hotspots from Laptop then most the time I am getting this same error.

Possible Solutions -

1. If you got this error try to call locManager.stopUpdatingLocation() and again call locManager.startUpdatingLocation().
2. Check your device having valid WIFI or 3G/2G Internet connection
3. Go to settings and reset your location services
4. Reset your network settings

Hope this will help you.

Comment: but, if i'm try with simulator and i set the default location how could that occure? :)

Comment: If you tried with iOS 8.x then you have to set custom location from simulator menu and if its not then its give you same error . If yo check with iOS 7.x simulator its never come with custom gpx file set.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question/answer but it does not consider the use case of the Simulator. That is, make sure that you ***do not have*** Debug > Location > None selected like so:

[image]

Be sure to select a valid location like Apple's HQ in Cupertino for instance:

[image]